# How to count 1 in a int variable

Tags: c, binary

If I have a `int i = 15;` I know  it is `0x00 00 00 0F` in binary is `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111` has 4 `1` in binary.

I want to count the sum of `1` in a int variable.

I write this:

```
int count1(int i)
{
    int j = 0,num = 0;
    for(;j<32;j++)
        if((i<<j )&0x80000000)
            num++;
    return num;
}
```

It can work, but I think it is too slow,I mean maybe I have millions `int` data. Dose some one have a more effective way to do this?

Comment: [This](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) link also provides several ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main() 
{ 

    int number = 15; 
    int sum; // total bits set in number
    for (sum = 0; number; sum++)
    {
      number &= number - 1; 
    }
    cout<<sum<<endl;
}
```

Comment: If it is faster ,can you explain why?

Comment: It uses less CPU instructions to calculate the number of SET bits. I read it in one link. Let me search that link for you. In that link, he has explained so many other ways to calculate number of set bits. But I found the above method easy.

Comment: I read the link and find this answer .

Comment: @LidongGuo this logic works faster because it need not loop through all the bits(for example no need of 32 iteration for a 4 byte variable), it can just loop through only set number of bits(ie., if 2 bits are set than just iterate 2 times only). But things will be different if all the bits of a variable is set, in this case any method will consume same execution.

Answer (score 2):

```
int countSetBits(int n)
{
    unsigned int count = 0;
    while (n)
    {
      n &= (n-1) ;
      count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

This method of counting the set bits in a number is called **Brian Kernighan’s Algorithm**, where the loop will iterate only upto the number of set bits. ie., in your case of example this will loop through 4 times only and need not loop the entire 32 times.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
int countOnes (int i) {

    int num = 0;
    while (i) {
        if (i % 2)
            num++;
        i = i >> 1;
    }

    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply keep on trimming the number. Let us assume that the binary number is stored in an int variable bin.

//This Function accepts binary value to count how many ones are there in it.

```
int count(int bin)
{
    int num=0;
    while(bin>=1)
    {
        if(bin%10 == 1)
        {
            num++;
        }
        bin=bin/10;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is right for your assumption, but this is not what is asked.